# Bash script executed with curl - Gum not working

Tags: bash, nginx, curl

I have a simple nginx server serving a `test.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash
gum input
echo hello
echo world
ls -l
```

If I'm doing `./test.sh` it is working file.
I can see the gum input

```
> Type something...
```

and only after I entered something and pressed enter, I can see my entered string and the script continues

```
Hi
hello
world
...
```

If I'm doing `curl 127.0.0.1/test.sh | bash`, it is not working.
I have

```
> echo hello echo world ls -l    *
```

ps : I replaced the caret with *

and after entering something the script does not continue

```
echo hello echo world ls -l  hi
```

I don't understand what's the problem.  I don't know if it is coming from nginx, from curl or from gum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `bash` is receiving its stdin from the pipeline and not your terminal, so you can't interact with it like a script that you run directly. You have to read from somewhere other than stdin since you are already using that for something else.

The best option is for your `gum` command to read from a different file descriptor. Usually something like this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash
gum input <&3
echo hello
echo world
ls -l
```

And then you invoke with `curl 127.0.0.1/test.sh | bash 3<&1`

---

Another option if you don't like playing with file descriptors is to use a process substitution:

`bash <( curl 127.0.0.1/test.sh )`

This frees up the stdin for `bash` by replacing the pipeline with a special temporary file containing the output of `curl`.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand. It's working fine.  Even if I don't find that solution "clean" (for me) mainly for the 3<&1 in the curl.

Comment: @tweetysat I added an alternative if you don't like file descriptors

Comment: Eventually I chose the second solution.  But how can I run the script as root ?  I tried `sudo bash <( curl 127.0.0.1/test.sh )` but I receive only `bash: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's probably worth its own question so you can get a thorough answer. It's a tricky problem because `sudo` causes all file descriptors other than the default ones to be closed for security reasons. If you don't want to download and run the script in two separate steps you probably need to look at the `-C`/`--close-from` options of `sudo` and read the manual on how to configure them to leave your file descriptors open.